# Minha rota localhost:3000/files/ não mostra a imagem ( express.static não retorna a imagem)

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, aplicação-web, express.js

Na minha rota de arquivos estáticos, ela encontra a imagem mas retorna apenas o binário dela e não a imagem em si para a visualização.

Oque eu quero é poder visualizar a imagem ao colocar no navegador por exemplo: **localhost:3000/files/imagem1.jpg**

```
app.use('/files', express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'));
```

**index.js da API**

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require("express");
var cors = require('cors');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

var router = require("./routes/routes");

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type");
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    next();
   });
// parse application/json
app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.json());

app.use('/files', express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'));


app.use("/api", router);

app.listen(3000, function(){ console.log('Servidor Web rodando na porta 3000') });
```

O retorno no navegador é esse da imagem abaixo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
inserir a descrição da imagem aqui

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e depois o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70). Sobre o print fornecido, aparenta ser uma  imagem JPEG corretamente formatada (mas servida com o content-type errado, o browser mostra como texto).

Comment: Obrigado pela colocação, irei melhor nas próximas, essa foi a minha primeira pergunta no site. 
Já postei a solução, talvez tenha faltado comentar com detalhes, mas logo irei editala melhor.

Comment: Se eu entendi bem sua resposta, o que pode ter feito funcionar foi o fato de tirar o header errado `res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");`. Melhor seria explicitar  como image/jpeg (mas é uma suposição com base no que foi fornecido)

Comment: acredito que por conta deste trecho " res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");" todos os meus retornos estavam sendo em json, mas ainda não tenho certeza sobre isso, assim que verificar outros pontos detalharei melhor a resposta.

Comment: De qq forma, recomendo uma lida nos links passados para conseguir um retorno mais eficaz nas próximas, e para ajudar compor o acervo  do site.

Comment: Sim, tirarei um tempo para dar uma lida nos links, mais uma vez obrigado.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');

const router = require("./routes/routes");
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.json());

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use('/files', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/uploads')));

app.use('/api', router);

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Servidor Web rodando na porta 3000')
});
```

Answer (score -1):

É que você está mudando o cabeçalho da resposta para retornar um JSON. Tenta salvar o cors em uma variável e passar apenas na rota que você quer habilitar. Algo assim mais ou menos...

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

const router = require("./routes/routes");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

const configCors = function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'content-type');
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
};

app.options('*', configCors);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.json());

app.use('/files', express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'));

app.use('/api', configCors, router);

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Servidor Web rodando na porta 3000')
});
```